# What is a Queen Vampire doing in my fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

This is the first time my fortress was promoted to Mountainhome before flooding with water, lava or HFS, so I don't know if this is expected. I got a message that the King had arrived with his entourage. Checking the Nobles screen, I see:

> Dodók Kûbukthabum, **queen vampire** 
>   ... 
>   One Hundred Ninety-Six Kills 
>   Eighty-eight dwarves in Scorchedtraded 
>   Ninety-four dwarves in Scorchedtraded 
>   ... When possible, she prefers to consume giant jackal. 
>   ... She has a shortage of patience.

Should I worry? If she was a real vampire, she wouldn't be bragging about it and put "Vampire" in her title, right? If she *is* a vampire and I kill her, will I get a new king/queen?

Edit: Also, she has the scary `Ñ` symbol but is still friendly. So I suppose she's a normal vampire-turned-politician?

Comment: +1 for the "normal" vampire turned politician: this phrase tells a lot about politics...:-S

Comment: "One Hundred Ninety-Six Kills". Yeah, enjoy having her stay :S

Comment: @TrewTzu well, you've got to do *something* with those migrant fish dissectors.

Comment: Vampires are disproportionately represented in dwarven politics, due to their unlimited age allowing them to up their skills ad infinitum. My current mayor is a vamp too; he's got his own rooms that he's never used, and a little hole in the loam wall that he does use; I'm in a terrifying embark, and his friendship with the zombies defending/infesting the surface is very useful to the fort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't get a replacement ruler if your current one meets an (un)timely end. She sounds like a real vampire. Confining her to a blocked-off area filled with migrants sounds like the best solution. Or you could make a queen zoo with a crystal clear glass enclosure in the middle of your grand dining room. Drop in some critters and miscreants and enjoy the spectacle.

It may have been discovered that she's a vampire after she'd become the queen, so she couldn't be chased out.

This isn't particularly exotic, people get elf and human kings often enough (and you can't become an elf or a human if you're a dwarf, unlike with vampires), though this situation certainly has more fun potential.

Comment: I like the queen zoo idea. :D

Comment: Will she need anything in a confinement, such as food, water or new clothes? Or can I just lock her in?

Comment: Vampires don't have any physical needs except for blood, which they drink from sleeping dwarves. She's not going to be happy about being on display naked, but probably won't go crazy over it. Should be easy enough to dump some poorly-dyed pig tail clothes every year or 2 though.

Comment: Or just let her steal clothing from the migrants you put in there with her after she's gobbled them up.

Comment: Actually, is there any downside to having a vampire as your queen? Will the Hammerer still try to dispense "justice" if he catches her in the act?

Comment: @Landric not really, since you can always isolate a vampire (assuming you know who it is, of course), and an isolated vampire is the perfect "time capsule" to make your fort essentially immortal - even if all the other dwarves die, the single surviving vampire will hold until new migrants arrive.